# Calling a JS Function with Axios inside it Returns Undefined when called

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

The function `isAdmin('foo')` will return true or false if user with alias `foo` has any of the specified roles bound to it.

Here's the code:

```
export function isAdmin(alias, adminRoleOverride) {
try {
    axios.get('https://xxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxx/xxxx/' + alias)
    .then(function (response) {
        var admin = false;
        var aliasBoundRoles = response.data; //An array with the roles the alias currently holds.

        var adminRolePolicy = ['SuperAdmin', 'Admin', 'Director', 'RegionalManager',
            'TrainingManager', 'SiteTrainer', 'SitePOC', 'OutSourceSitePocManager']; //What is considered an admin.
        if(adminRoleOverride){
            adminRolePolicy = adminRoleOverride;
        } //If an array with roles is passed as param, override the default adminRolePolicy.

        admin = aliasBoundRoles.some((role) => {
            return adminRolePolicy.includes(role);
        }); //If any of the aliasBoundRoles is in the adminRolePolicy return true else false.
        return admin;
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error when attempting to authorize user " + alias + "."
    + "\nError: " + error);
    return false;
}  
}
```

I would like to use the function as follows:

```
if(isAdmin('foo')){
    console.log("YAAAY")
}
```

.. but it wont work cause when the `if-block` gets evaluated `isAdmin('foo')` is still undefined, hasn't returned.

I know it has to do something with the fact that the axios call is async and takes time to pull the data.

How can I get this to work, any help would be greatly appreciated and if you have any tutorials about this I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I'd look at redefining `isAdmin`... that's the name of the function and you're re-setting it to the line with `aliasBoundRoles.some...`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, im going to fix that right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you wanna do the following

```
export function isAdmin(alias, adminRoleOverride) {
try {
    // return the promise
    return axios.get('https://xxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxx/xxxx/' + alias)
    .then(function (response) {
        var admin = false;
        var aliasBoundRoles = response.data; //An array with the roles the alias currently holds.

        var adminRolePolicy = ['SuperAdmin', 'Admin', 'Director', 'RegionalManager',
            'TrainingManager', 'SiteTrainer', 'SitePOC', 'OutSourceSitePocManager']; //What is considered an admin.
        if(adminRoleOverride){
            adminRolePolicy = adminRoleOverride;
        } //If an array with roles is passed as param, override the default adminRolePolicy.

        admin = aliasBoundRoles.some((role) => {
            return adminRolePolicy.includes(role);
        }); //If any of the aliasBoundRoles is in the adminRolePolicy return true else false.
        return admin;
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error when attempting to authorize user " + alias + "."
    + "\nError: " + error);
    return Promise.resolve(false);
}  
}
```

and later

```
// this code should be inside an async function
const hasRoleAdmin = await isAdmin('foo')
if(hasRoleAdmin){
    console.log("YAAAY")
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. It's complaining about `await` being a reserved word. I have to put it inside the async function as you said right?

Comment: @DanielSegura yes this should be inside an async function

Comment: Now im wondering if this is good architecture. Doesn't it seem wierd that I have to encapsulate my whole code (Say +300 lines of other stuff) around this async just to check if its authorized. Is there a better way of doing this while being able to reuse the function in multiple places?

Comment: You should break your code into smaller functions, each function doing one thing and one thing only , and doing it correctly. you for sure don't want 300+ lines under one if statement

Comment: Im using .ejs so this part of the code helps what to render depending on the user elevation so thats why its +300 lines. I agree I should break it apart but what I meant is that it doesn't seem right that I have to encapsulate everything inside a async function just to check if the user is authorized. You know? This solves the problem and you definitely answered my question (thanks!) but I may be solving it the wrong way :P

Comment: network requests are async by nature, the only way to get an answer from an async operation is after its finished, and this is what await is doing, the fact that you are encapsulating the  functionality inside the function is good regardless if the function is async or not ( whether its async or not will depend on what the function is doing and how its doing). That said, "await"is the latest and best syntax in javascript that is intended for handling async code

Comment: Thank you for your help and clarifications!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get an async result when Promises are involved is to use an async function and await the result:

```
async function codeDoingTheCheck() {
  const isAuthorized = await isAdmin('foo');
  if (isAuthorized) {
    console.log("YAAAY")
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that `codeDoingTheCheck` is now also async, so whatever calls it has to await its result (and whatever calls that, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for helping! Wrapping it around an async function seems odd and now im asking myself if there is a better way of doing this. I just want to be able to check if the user is an admin. I also want to be able to use the function in multiple places thats why I made placed it in its own file and am importing it

Comment: You can't make any async code in JavaScript non-async. You must use async functions or callbacks.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for answering my initial question. On my prev comment I just meant that maybe I can solve the problem with a different approach. Cause it seems odd that I have to encapsulate everything inside an async function JUST for this particular use case.